# How to get keys from Array of tuple in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, tuples

I am getting a dictionary [String: Int] from API, sorting it by value. In that, I am getting an Array of Tuple, in that array of tuple I need to separate the keys and want to make an array with that keys in that same sorted order.

I tried a way to get the object from that array and added it into a dictionary, but it is not working fine, because the dictionary is getting unordered while adding or after adding the keys, need help to resolve this issue

Tried code

```swift
let personalInfoDict = screenConfigResponse?.screenConfiguration?.personalInformation
let personalDict : [String : Int]?
if let dict = personalInfoDict, dict.count > 0 {
    personalDict = self.sortWithKeys(dict)
}

func sortWithKeys(_ dict: [String: Int]) -> [String: Int] {
    let sorted = dict.sorted(by: { $0.value < $1.value })
    var newDict: [String: Int] = [:]
    for sortedDict in sorted {
        newDict[sortedDict.key] = sortedDict.value
    }
    return newDict
}
```

When doing sort I got in a correctly sorted order, but when I loop and add it in newDict, it is going unordered, is there any way to get only the keys from the Array of tuples

Comment: `Dictionary` aren't sorted, that's why your code doesn't work. After all it's a key access, not an index access. There is now a new object which is a sorted dictionary which is `OrderedDictionary`. See https://www.advancedswift.com/ordereddictionary/#ordereddictionary-maintains-insertion-order

Comment: @Larme Ok, will check this, thanks of sharing this article

Comment: @Larme However, you have to add that package separately, that's not part of core Swift.

Comment: Yes @Sulthan, is there any other way to do it, without adding that package

Comment: Sort the keys into a new array and then use that array when accessing the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can transform it to an array of tuple:

```
let personalInfoDict = screenConfigResponse?.screenConfiguration?.personalInformation
let personalPairs = personalInfoDict
    .reduce(into: [(String, Int)]()) { $0.append(($1.key, $1.value)) }
    .sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })

 if let pArray = personalPairs, pArray.count > 0 {
    for obj in pArray {
       personalInformationArray.append(obj.0)
    }
 }
```

Now you have a `[(String, Int)]` ordered array

Comment: I tried this code, I am getting sorted dict alphabetically, but I want it to be sorted with value, means sorting with that integer

Comment: I changed the sorting with 0.0 to 0.1 and 1.0 to 1.1, then it got sorted with the value, now I want to get only the keys in this, in a separate array, you know I can do that

Comment: Why do you want another with only the keys? It has great chances of become desynchronized with `personalPairs`. It can be done though, but everytime you do an operatton on `personalPairs` you need to reflect it on the other one... `let otherOnes = personalParis.map { $0.0 }`

Comment: @Larme My requirement is to get sorted key array only, for that only I did sorting that dictionary with value and tried to get the sorted keys alone in an array. And, Yes I am got it by other one only like you suggested, Thanks

Comment: @iDevid I got it by looping personalPairs, Thank you so much.

Comment: @iDevid `.reduce(into: [(String, Int)]()) { $0.append(($1.key, $1.value)) }` is just equivalent to `.map { ($0.key, $0.value) }`, which i think is just equal to `.map { $0 }`, or not doing anything at all and just calling the sort.

Answer (score 0):

For literature dictionaries, there is a type of HashTables.
But HashTables **are not ordered** data structures, so the effect you get is expected behavior.

However, Apple provides an optional package that adds to your project other data structures (https://github.com/apple/swift-collections). In particular I think "OrderedDictionary" is your solution.

```
let baseDict : [String:Int] = ["Test1" : 5,
                                   "Test2" : 1,
                                   "Test3" : 4]

let orderedDict : OrderedDictionary<String, Int> = sortWithKeys(baseDict: baseDict)
print(orderedDict)

func sortWithKeys(baseDict : [String:Int]) -> OrderedDictionary<String, Int>
{
    let temp = baseDict.sorted(by: { $0.value < $1.value })
    var newDict : OrderedDictionary<String, Int> = [:]
    for element in temp {
        newDict[element.key] = element.value
    }
    return newDict
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AntonioWar, The above answer helped me to achieve it without adding  Swift Collection. Thank you for your time to help me